# Как убрать изменение которые появляются сразу в 2х ветках?

Tags: git, phpstorm

В кратце

Есть 2 ветки master и Issue#100

При изменении в ветке Issue#100 и переходе обратно на ветку master все изменения, что я сделал в Issue#100 появляются и в master.

И наоборот При изменении в ветке master и переходе обратно на ветку Issue#100 все изменения, что я сделал в master появляются и в Issue#100.

Comment: Если вы эти изменения не коммитили, то это совершенно нормальное поведение. Сделайте коммит в `Issue#100` и перейдите в мастера - всё будет ОК

Comment: но раньше такого не было
в плане ветка master была сама по себе
а ветка Issue#100 сама по себе 
не было такого, что изменения в одной резко переходили к другой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась после перехода в другую ветку и отправкой коммита[git commit, git push]